# Группировка в TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Имеется массив, состоящий из объектов:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *zArray;
```

У каждого объекта есть поле `@property int category` и оно может быть равно от 1 до 23 включительно.

Каким образом можно сформировать TableView, чтобы группировка в ней была по этому полю?

И как потом через segue узнать по какому полю был клик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sectionsData;
```

дальше пакуем это дело в удобный для нас формат:

```
NSMutableArray *sectionsToSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 23];
for (int i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
    NSArray *items = [self.zArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"category == %d", i];
    sectionsToSet[i] = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: items, @"items"];
    // используя такой инициализатор для NSDictionary даже если items будут nil, все будет норм. 
    // NSDictionary здесь только для того, чтобы в будущем вы могли добавить данные в ваши секции, например заголовок:
    // sectionsToSet[i] = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"SOME TITLE": @"title", items, @"items"];
    // На самом деле можно просто сетить массив:
    /*
       if (items.count) { sectionsToSet[i] = items; } else { sectionsToSet[i] = @[]; }
    */
}
self.sectionsData = sectionsToSet.copy;
```

ну и дальше:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return self.sectionsData.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [self.sectionsData[section][@"items"] count];
   // либо если там массив: return [self.sectionsData[section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyObject *object = [self.sectionsData[indexPath.section][@"items"][indexPath.row];
   // для массива: [self.sectionsData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   if (indexPath) {
      /* тут получаем объект также, как в cellForRowAtIndexPath: */
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подробный ответ! А как потом через -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender, можно узнать по какому полю был клик?

Comment: @Chekist проапдейтил ответ для segue

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы имеете ввиду секции в TableView, то  вот так:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Тут нужно можно указать название у каждой секции. Например, первая секция "1 секция", а остальные "Остальные секции"
    if (section == 0)
        return @"1 секция";

    return @"Остальные секции";
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Тут указываем сколько всего секции. Например,
    return zArray.count;
}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Тут нужно указать сколько ячеек в каждой секции, Например в первой data1.count, во остальный data2.count
    if (section == 0)
        return self.data1.count;

    return self.data2.count;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Тут можно кастомизировать секцию: высота, цвет, шрифт и так далее
    view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.497 green:0.649 blue:0.000 alpha:0.490];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

   // Тут уже настраиваем сами ячейки в зависимости от секции

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = data1[indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = data2[indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Можете так же посмотреть [вот этот туториал](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/)

А так же [документацию Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html)